# Display string with bold letters in Dialog message

Tags: android, dialog, formatting, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment

Let's say I had this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
    .setMessage("I want THIS word to be bold and the rest normal!")
    .create().show();
```

Is there any way to have Android apply formatting or bold font to parts of the text string?

Comment: Take a look at [SpannableString](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html)

Comment: Found a different solution involving Html.fromHtml() which appears to work well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a string to your strings.xml like this:

```
<string name="bold_message">I want <b>THIS</b> word to be bold and the rest normal!</string>
```

and then in your alert dialog just use `setMessage(R.string.bold_message)`

Answer (score 2):

Using Spannable string is easy way

In your string.xml add

```
<string name = "bold_message"><![CDATA[<p>This want <b>THIS</b> word to bold and the rest normal!</p>]]></string>
```

In your alert dialog

```
.setMessage(Html.fromHtml(R.string.bold_message);
```

Answer (score 1):

Some extra information.

Let's say the `string resource` is like

```
<string name="bold_text">This is <b>bold</b> text.</string>
```

Set this `string resource` to a `Dialog` as `.setMessage(R.string.bold_text)` or as a `CharSequence` like `.setMessage(context.getResource.getText(R.string.bold_text))`.

`.setMessage(context.getString(R.string.bold_text))` will display the entire text as normal (no bold).

Answer (score -2):

You must use custom dialogs . Default Android dialogs don't have any option to do this .
For more info refer to :
[Custom Dialog Android](https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/)