# Alert dialog: a string is not converting to bold text

Tags: java, android

I have looked at this question to help with placing bold text in a java string. 
[Display string with bold letters in Dialog message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40430115/display-string-with-bold-letters-in-dialog-message)

I used the second answer but to be fair the first answer can be applied to.

I want to bold my text but it is not displaying as bold and compared to the answers given in the previous question somebody gave, I am unsure why my text is not displaying as bold.

This is for an android application and the variable for message is passed as a String parameter to be used within an alert dialog.

strings,xml:

```
<resources>
    <string name="bold_yellow"><![CDATA[<b>yellow</b>]]></string>
</resources>
```

in the class:

```
ShowRewardDialog("Test " + Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.bold_yellow)) + " Bold");
```

Below is the showRewardDialog() method:

```
private void ShowRewardDialog(String message) {

        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Content.this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);

        SpannableString title = new SpannableString("YOU GAINED A REWARD");

        title.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Content.this.getResources().getColor(R.color.purple))
                , 0, title.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
        TextView text = dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_text);
        dialog.setTitle(title);

        text.setText(message);

        Button dialogButton = dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_button_OK);
        // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
        dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: What is `ShowRewardDialog`? Add the code

Comment: I've andded the ShowRewardDialog method in my question

Comment: You using already using a custom view . Then why not just set `android:textStyle="bold"` to textview in xml ? Using `SpannableString` for full length also does not make any sense its equal to setting text color in xml .

Comment: @I don't want all the text to be bold, just one word in the dialog

Comment: Then Use `StyleSpan`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a spannable string, just like the one for the title:

```
        SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(message);
        spannableString.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), start, length, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
        text.setText(spannableString);
```

start is the index of the 1st char to be bold and length is the length of the bold string.

Comment: so if I want to do the word yellow and then later the word red, how will your answer support the text change?

Comment: Just like you made the title purple.